# Hotmail and IP in blacklist - how to solve now?

Tags: email, ip-address, blacklist, hotmail

Our server's IP address is blacklisted by the provider of **hotmail**.

We can't find any solutions. We followed up with all the instructions they gave us in the DEAMON email link, but it's not enough - the IP is still banned.

Do you know how to contact them or how to solve this problem at least easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hotmail, which is operated under Outlook.com now, is provided by Microsoft. You can request they remove your IP address by completing the form [here](https://support.msn.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl&ct=eformts) (this may require signing up for Outlook.com first).

It will take a few days for them to investigate the report, and if your IP address was not associated with sending Spam, you'll receive an email back from their support team. It will then take another 24-48 hours for the IP address to be fully unblocked in their system.

You should also test your IP address in a multi-RBL check site like [this](http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/) one. Visit each site that your IP address is listed in and test it there to see what message they relay back. If there's something you can address, then do so and request that they remove your IP address from their list.

It may also be wise to setup and configure [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [PTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) records in the DNS for your mail server, as well as [DomainKeys Identified Mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail).

Comment: Hi i submitted the form loggin in with my hotmail account, the problem is that the form ,once submitted, doesn't shows any confirm message that the form was successfull, unbelievable, thanks for your tips man :)

Comment: I was also blacklisted and actually wanted to give up on it, but then found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=635707736344041971) URL. It fixed the problem in a day.

Comment: Use the link that Tobias provided to the request form, since the URL has since changed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I submitted [this form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=635954599533189814) and after some days my IP was de-listed.