# Who to contact when my server is on a Gmail blacklist?

Tags: google, email, gmail, blacklist

I am facing an IP blacklist problem when sending email to Gmail the emails are flagged as SPAM.

The headers and the email body are following the Google guidelines and there is really no-reason why it should be spam, since I've sent about 10 emails in my life from this server.

Do you know how to contact Google or submit some help request?

Comment: Is it on a blacklist for sure, or just marked as spam?

Comment: Check http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to make sure you are not on a blacklist. GMail does not run a blacklist but does check them. If you are on a blacklist, you can follow the instructions in the details to remove your site from the list.

Comment: See [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54988/how-to-remove-our-ip-address-from-microsofts-email-blacklist) and [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53428/hotmail-and-ip-in-blacklist-how-to-solve-now) for previous questions from the OP that are similar.

Comment: Which guidelines are you referring to? Gmail requires a lot of headers and authentication such as DKIM and SPF records. Make sure you have those enabled and correctly configured.

Answer (score 3):

Typically an organization like Spamhaus.org will maintain those kinds of lists. If you find out which organization blacklisted you, they are usually pretty good about getting you removed if you contact them.